# Read logs on Jelly Bean (without permission, maybe with root?)

Tags: android, root, logcat, android-logcat

I'm looking for a way to read logs on Android Jelly Bean. I know, that the respective permission isn't granted anymore, that's why I'm asking for an alternative.

Is root access a possibility?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know that *the respective permission isn't granted anymore*?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371021/reading-activitymanager-logs-on-a-jelly-bean-device

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461650