# Detect when an external android app runs onCreate, onStart, onResume methods

Tags: android

I want to know how to detect when an external app runs one of this methods. I'm working with some classmates in a project where we want to examinate the response time of other applications. The idea is to measure the time between the run of each method to get an aproximation of the response time when opening the app.

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is imprecise, but I would monitor logcat activity. Depending on the device/VM/AVD logcat is super active during transitions (such as back-grounding and foregrounding) and idle when an app is awaiting user input.

EDIT:
Other than that, if you can do your analysis off the device, perhaps look into using [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html)?

Comment: But i want to measure the response time, from a service, so i think the logcat wont help me in this case. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: There's always reading logcat [programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692103/read-logcat-programmatically-within-application) on the device. In the past I've parsed logcat using adb and a python script to profile applications.

Comment: Hey, i was able to read the real response time thrown by the Activity Manager. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Hi, i am reading the logcat by using READ_LOGS permission. This permission is not available in devices running Jelly Bean and above(4.1 and above). Do you know if there is any other way of reading the ActivityManager logs in jelly bean ?

Comment: There are a couple of questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461650/read-logs-permission-on-jelly-bean-api-16) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371021/reading-activitymanager-logs-on-a-jelly-bean-device) of using a package manager to grant the permission. However, if you want an app-driven reader it looks like google engineered that capability away. Unless your app is going to run on root devices, this appears to be a standing constraint.

Comment: Yes, i am afraid i am not able to run the app on root devices. Will check the links, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Android apps are sandboxed and only expose content that they intend to expose. The methods you name are part of components that cannot be accessed directly from the "outside" world. In other ways, if an app wanted you to know when those methods are being called, they will expose that information (i.e. sending a `Broadcast` or maybe storing the information in a `ContentProvider`). You can try and see if you can get some information out of the logcat, but I cannot assure how accurate and consistent it will be.

Comment: Yeah, that is what i thought. Do you know if there is some sort of android log where the OS may store the run of this methods?

Comment: Or if anyone have any other ideas on how to measure the response time of external apps, please let me know :)

Comment: By response time, you mean when the `LAUNCHER` `Activity` initiates after the `Intent` is sent?

Comment: I want to be able to measure time when the app is opening or being launched, and when the gui is fully loaded and the user can use it. In other words how long does the app takes to load.

Comment: Yeah, I do not know how you would do that from an external app.

Comment: Thanks, i will wait a few hours for other answers, before accepting yours.